# Making query from variable from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm going mad here...

I want to

```
SELECT `id` FROM `colors` 
  WHERE `colors.id=1` 
    AND `cars.user=1` 
    AND `colors.car=cars.id`
```

.

from my tables

```
users
id, name
1, Nicolas
2, John

cars
id, user, name
1, 1, Mercedes
2, 2, Ferrari

colors
id, car, name
1, 1, Black
2, 2, Red
```

This database means, that Nicolas have Black Mercedes and John have Red Ferrari.
For example, if I use a SELECT statement with WHERE`colors.id=1` AND `cars.user=2` it needs to return me an empty result.

Comment: Your database schema is wrong if you ask me. You should have 1 table for cars, 1 for users and 1 for colors, then 1 extra table linking the whole thing together with car_id_color_id and user_id as fields. The you can use stuff like joins very easilly.

Comment: Yes, or just to add `user` on colors, too... then I'll select colors.id with colors.user much more easier.

Comment: No, this would be equally wrong regarding database normalization. Why make things another way when the normalized way is that logical ? You did put those things in different tables because you felt you had to... push it further the way I suggest, it will be more bullet proof and your insert/update queries will be way easier to write.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make it this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JOIN to get result from all the tables.

```
SELECT u.name AS UserName, c.name AS CarName, col.name AS CarColor FROM users AS u
JOIN cars AS c ON (c.user = u.id)
JOIN colors AS col on (col.car = c.id)
WHERE u.id = 1;
```